# Play Framework 2.3 OAUTH 2 Java Provider

Tags: rest, playframework, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.3

I know that it might be an old question, But I didn't find a solution for it. I need an Oauth2 Provider (not client) to secure my APIs that works on play framework java (not scala). I think this is important, any one reached for a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

The master branch of securesocial have support for play 2.3. Here is the project website: http://securesocial.ws/ . There isn't a stable version right now.

Comment: securesocial is an OAuth **client** implementation, not a **provider**